# Unable to import module after bundling with web pack

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6

I have the following index.js code:

```
import {Asp} from './src/asp.js';

export default Asp;
```

and the following run.js code:

```
import Asp from './dist/bundle.js'; // Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named 'default'
import Asp from './index.js'; // works

const myASP = new Asp();
```

and webpack (3.11) config file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" }
        ]
    }
};
```

I can't figure out why using the bundle.js doesn't work when I import...help...

**UPDATE:**

I gave up on webpack and moved to rollup with the following configuration which solved my problem:

```
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';

export default {
    input: 'src/index.js',
    output:{
        file: 'dist/index.js',
        name: 'Asp',
        format: 'es'
    },
    plugins: [
        uglify()
    ]
}
```

I couldn't figure out what was the equivalent to this in webpack - but it did the job!

Comment: Why are you bundling it before importing it in the first place? Generally you'd only bundle it at the very end.

Comment: loganfsmyth - What do you mean? I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: Why do you have a `run.js` that imports `bundle.js`, instead of having `run.js` be the `entry` in your webpack config? Then you wouldn't import the bundle at all, just run it as a whole piece.

Comment: Loganfsmyth - I use run.js just for testing 'Asp' as a module. Like 'Asp' was a 3rd party object you could import to any project.

Comment: I'm confused. You said `import Asp from './index.js'; // works`, so I assumed you had a second setup to actually process those imports, but the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` error you're seeing now is because of those imports, not because of Webpack. Did you mean for `run.js` to use `require`?

Comment: run.js imports index.js which imports Asp.js. - This works for me.
After bundling with the entry point (index.js) I want run to ack the same. That's it. The error I'm getting is no "**Unexpected token**" but "**The requested module does not provide an export named 'default'**". As I mentioned below I added a small project that acts the same so you could see the issue there if you like github.com/kfirm/thirdPartyModuleTest

Answer (score 5):

By default Webpack outputs a Script file, meaning that it has no exports, so trying to import it into another file will not yield any results.

To tell Webpack to output the bundle as a reusable library, you need to tell it to do that with the [`output.libraryTarget`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget), so in your case you likely want to adjust

```
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
},
```

to be

```
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
},
```

Comment: Didn't work. :( I keep getting the same 'Uncaught SyntaxError' error messages

Comment: Please include the full error message, really hard to diagnose without that :)

Comment: I've put a small example of the issue here: https://github.com/kfirm/thirdPartyModuleTest

Comment: This worked for me. Before this change I was always getting an empty object when importing my library.

Answer (score 0):

In index.js file, you just need to import Asp, and remove the export line. So the index.js file will be:

```
import {Asp} from './src/asp.js';
```

In run.js

```
import {Asp} from './dist/bundle.js'; 

const myASP = new Asp();
```

Comment: Didn't work :(. Getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named 'Asp'"

Comment: What did you export in asp.js?

Comment: export class Asp {}