# Using webpack compiled library in another webpack project and nothing is imported

Tags: javascript, webpack

Let's say I have two projects:

`project-a`

```
export default "test text"
```

`project-a` is compiled using default webpack 4.0 config, which takes `/src/index.js` and bundles it to `/dist/main.js`.

I then saved it to my github or my npm so I can use it in future (like in project-b).

The package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "project-a",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "my project",
  "main": "./dist/main.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

---

`project-b`

I start by running:

```
npm install mygithub/project-a
```

Then using the same default webpack 4.0 config create an `/src/index.js` with:

```
import projectDefault from 'project-a'

console.log(projectDefault)
```

I get `{}`. Trying `import * as projectA from 'project-a'` yields `{}`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: does changing `export default "test text"` to `const text = "test text"; export default text` make a difference?

Comment: Just tried, didn't make a difference

Comment: I believe this also relates to my unanswered question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901262/unable-to-import-module-after-bundling-with-web-pack

Comment: @KfirM, yeah looks related. Someone said that people only bundle at the end - sure that's fine but then how would you create an importable npm project? Do you use the src file as the entry point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write some sort of reusable library, you have to tell webpack to do so.

```
output: {
  libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  library: 'handler',
  filename: 'index.js',
  path: path('build')
},
```

This is the important part. Here you are telling webpack that you want it to build a library.

As an example, take my [alexa-skill-template](https://github.com/danielbischoff/alexa-skill-template) project.
It exports the method *handle*.

Further reading:

- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget
- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library

Comment: I was told that in my question to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901262/unable-to-import-module-after-bundling-with-web-pack) ....But it didn't work... Will try this as well...

Comment: This works, it lets me import the compiled fine into another webpack project. However that same project can't be included as a script file.

Comment: Still can't get it to work on my end.... so frustrating...
@DavidAlsh - What do you mean by _can't be included as a script file_