# Webpack: npm module => ES6 Module to enable import

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6

Say I have some npm module with

```
...
exports.abc = abc;
exports.xyz = xyz;
```

...

I want to generate some lib.js file which allows me to do:

```
import {abc, xyz} from 'path/to/lib.js';
```

from a javascript file I'm including in a webpage with `<script type="module"></script>`

I've tried

`node_modules\.bin\webpack .\node_modules\package\lib.js -o .\path\to\lib.js --display-error-details --output-library my_lib`

But I can't see to do any imports. I've tried

```
import defaultExport from "path/to/lib.js";
import my_lib from "path/to/lib.js";
import {xyz} from "path/to/lib.js";
```

which all give me a variant of: `does not provide an export named '...'`

and

```
import "path/to/lib.js"
console.log(my_lib);
```

which throws a ReferenceError

Comment: Close voter, why is this off-topic?

Comment: Webpack works for me that way out of the box.

Comment: Can you build a wrapper of your own? just do `import * as Module from 'from/some/module.js';`?  Then just export the components you need, since Module then has everything including default

Comment: @Griffin — Recommendation questions aren't apropriate for SO.

Comment: Your edit doesn't stop this being a recommendation question.

Comment: @Quentin I'm looking for the standard way to do this. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: So as a relative outsider to the JS dev community, how do I found out what the consensus method for doing anything?

Comment: @JonasWilms Can you show me how you do it? I can't get it to work.

Comment: Not sure why it doesnt ...

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48978856/5260024